# How can I create a unique form for two separated Doctrine entities with Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two separate entities in my **Symfony2** app, namely **A** and **B**, which are mapped into a DB using the ORM **Doctrine2**.

Now, I want to create a unique webpage with a single form that includes all the fields from entities **A** and **B**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chapter about this in the Symfony documentation : [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: Well, this is not true. The tutorial that you are mentioning is related to two entities A and B which are not separated, since Tasks objects belong to multiple Tags objects! What about two entities that have no relationship?

Comment: If a user is going to fill two separate forms at once, it somehow suggests it should be related to each other, or at least to the user. Could you give us a more specific example of those entities?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it creating a form type like this:

```
class ComplexType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('entity_a', new SimpleAType(), array(
            ))
            ->add('entity_b', new SimpleBType(), array(
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'complex_type';
    }
}
```

When you call $form->getData() you should get an associative array with the objects. When you call $form->setData you should pass an associative array with the objects you want to set.

Comment: I'm going to test your solution. I'll give you a feedback asap.